How to get all image files from the gallery and list it. Expo react native
I need to display all the image files from the gallery . I am using expo react native.
What library should i use ?
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

async function getAllImageFiles() {
    if (permissionResponse?.status !== 'granted') {
      await requestPermission();
    }
    const fetchedAlbums = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync({});
    console.log(fetchedAlbums);
  }

when i log fetchedData i get :
[{"assetCount": 1, "id": "540528482", "title": "Download", "type": null}]
Please help me if any one knows

you might want to cross-check to see that you that permission is granted on the device you are using. Also consider doing some extra configuration from the expo docs
{
"expo": {
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-media-library",
    {
      "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
      "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
      "isAccessMediaLocationEnabled": true
    }
  ]
]}}

